# Passing data from 3 classes to one another in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, methods, delegates

I am unable to pass variables between 3 views in Objective C. I can pass data from one class to another as long as there are just 2, but if I add another view that needs to access the same delegate method, I am unable to do so.

Let me try to explain:

View1 accesses the delegate method declared in View2. However if I add another view called View3 and need to access delegate method for in View2, I cannot. I declared everything correctly and I am able to reference the delegate method, but still I cannot enter that reference in View3.

Comment: It's quite simple: When you create an object, set properties in the object that address the data you will need.  Or keep a pointer to the created object so that other objects can set properties at a later date.  It's a simple matter of addressability.

Answer (score 0):

Two objects can not be both the delegate of a third. Is that your issue? If so, consider using NSNotification in order to send messages: several objects can subscribe to notifications.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to passing data from 1 class to 3 classes , you had better use NSNotification.
you can use like this.

in the first receive class:

```
@implementation TestClass1

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveNotification1:) 
                                                 name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void) receiveNotification1:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"receive 1");
}

@end
```

in the 2nd receive class:

```
@implementation TestClass2

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveNotification2:) 
                                                 name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void) receiveNotification2:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"receive 2");
}

@end
```

in the 3rd receive class:

```
@implementation TestClass3

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receiveNotification3:) 
                                                 name:@"TestNotification"
                                               object:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void) receiveNotification3:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"receive 3");
}

@end
```

in the post class:

```
- (void) yourMethod
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" 
        object:self];

}
```